# Limit string to fixed length and open remaining string in modal popup (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

I have to limit a string length in the label if it exceeds 25 characters and display the entire string in a modal popup by making it a hyperlink.
Something like this: 
If my string is "Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", it should be displayed as:

Label: [Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy](http://google.com)

I just gave a hyperlink to www.google.com in my example but what I want is that a modal popup should open with the entire text.

I used this directive to limit the length: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/angularjs-how-to-limit-string-length-using-filterexample.html.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('limitChar', function () {
    return function (content, length, tail) {
    if (isNaN(length))
        length = 25; 

    if (tail === undefined)
        tail = "...";

    if (content.length <= length || content.length - tail.length <= length)  {
        return content;
    }

    else {
        return String(content).substring(0, length-tail.length) + tail;
    }
};
});
```

`

I am trying to make the "tail" as a hyperlink to open a modal popup where I can display the entire text. I tried something along these lines:

```
if (tail === undefined) {
 $sce.myHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="#" ng-click="showFullWord(content)">(more)</a>');
        tail = $sce.myHTML;
}
```

My function is

```
$scope.showFullWord = function (content) {
        $('#displayModal').modal('show');
        $scope.value = content;
    }
```

which is clearly not working. Can somebody give me an idea as to how I should proceed with this.

Comment: what does console say?

Comment: Can You just show the "tail" in tooltip hint, opening on hover?

Comment: @manish: do you mean the console in F12 tools?

Comment: @Razzka: No, I need it in a popup.

Comment: @manish 
I only have this error on console.
TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: @niharika there you go, that it, look for it

Comment: @manish: My text is getting cut to the required length. I am having a problem with the hyperlink.